# How to remove unnecessary columns in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How do I remove unnecessary columns from Quotation View (for example, Requested Date, Commitment Date and Salesperson)?

[image]

I cannot find respective fields in Three View:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<tree string="Sales Orders" decoration-bf="message_needaction==True" decoration-muted="state=='cancel'">

    <field name="message_needaction" invisible="1"/>

    <field name="pricelist_id"/>

    <field name="name" string="Order Number"/>

    <field name="date_order"/>

    <field name="partner_id"/>

    <field name="user_id"/>

    <field name="amount_total" sum="Total Tax Included" widget="monetary"/>

    <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>

    <field name="invoice_status"/>

    <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
</tree>
```

Answer (score 1):

For hiding any of the field from tree view you need to add argument `invisible=1` in **`.xml`** file of relevant view. If you are not getting the field as you told then that tree view might be inherited by any other module. For checking that you can follow the steps: **activate developer mode** >> **click on 'bug icon' located on right top of screen** >> click on **edit list view option** >> then one tab is there inside that **inherited views**. Open any of that and check the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have installed "Dates on Sales Order" module. It adds Requested Date, Commitment Date and Effective Date fields. You can uninstall this module to remove the fields. The field "Salesperson" is standard Odoo field user_id. You can locate this field in the xml in your question. You can inherit the standard view and remove this field.